# How to bundle NextJS project into one single file

Tags: webpack, next.js

I'm currently building a project that will work as an addon to another application. I'm currently using NextJS to build the application, but I need to bundle the NextJS JavaScript files into only one. Is that possible?

Comment: Please check the link for more information - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5708

Comment: Next JS is combination of Server side rendering and Client side rendering. If you just need static files from your code, then you are not using the SSR of next JS?.
Have you tried next export? -
Update your build script in package.json to use next export:
"scripts": {
  "build": "next build && next export"
}

more info here - https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Answer (score 3):

`next export` will [export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) all your pages to static HTML files that you can serve with any host (similarly to create-react-app). You can use this as an addon as you can get your pre-existing application to just render the html files at specific endpoints.

However this doesn't bundle everything into a single `.js` file, but this is the closest you will get. If `next export` doesn't satisfy your use case maybe its worth asking why you need to bundle everything into a single js file specifically, and if its just JS you need - then why use Next?